# Extracting values from second brackets in a string

Tags: regex

Struggling to write Regex for the following can anyone help pls:

String1 = `[The Aggregate Total Incremental Facility Commitments shall not, at any time, exceed [10 million].]`

Output Expected: String1 = `10 million`

String2 = `a Borrower (or the Parent) may select an Interest Period of [[ 12] or [24]] Months`

Output Expected: String2 = `[[ 12] or [24]] Months`

String3 = `excluding all intra-group items and investments in Subsidiaries of any member of the Group) exceeds [10]% of [ABC]`

Output Expected: `String 3 = [10]%`

Comment: Have you tried anything so far you could share with us?

Comment: this gives value if there are only single brackets (means not twice) - @"\[(.*?)\]";

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place --- the question.

Comment: Is your string2 expected output correct? you've included the word "Months", even though that doesn't appear to be in any sort of brackets in the input string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
regex1 = (?!.*\[)(.*?)\].*$  // for string1
regex2 = \[[^"]*      // for string2
regex3 = \[.*?\]%     // for string3
```

[demo regex2](https://regex101.com/r/XY9nlQ/1)

[demo regex3](https://regex101.com/r/kScqPA/1)

Comment: Second and Third regex not working for me. Can you help

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: asp.net c# language

Comment: it is working for me in testers, i dont know how you are using it. but you can try, `(\[[^"]*)` and `(\[.*?\]%)` if you are taking group 1.

Answer (score 0):

This works for you specific test cases but without knowing why/how you got them test cases I can't make it work for additional cases:

```
.*(\[.*?\]%).*|(?:^[\[]?.*?\[(.*?)\]).*|.*(\[\[.*\]\].\w+)
```

This doesn't include the *String x =* sorry.

[regexr.com/40b58](https://regexr.com/40b58)